# FFT results are repeating?

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, audio, audio-processing

I am trying to detect notes out of a musical sound input. My program can be [run here](https://codepen.io/doganmeh/pen/MWyzxrY). The problem is the patterns in the frequency response is repeating:
[image]

I suspect that echoing in the room is causing the higher frequency components. If I try a sound generator such as [this](https://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/), repetition is much less, but it is there. Try for example 165 Hz (note E3).

My primary question is that, how come sometimes repetitions have higher spikes in FFT than the actual signal (see the above image). This happens once in a while when human voice is tested. I know the actual signal is the 1st one because I test it in another software (Singer's Studio on iPhone).

Answer (score 2):

Interesting code! This was tough to follow from the pictures, but I did run the OP's code from the linked site, I can't play the sound loud enough to really test but appears to not be very sensitive for lower volume signals. There is no indication of the frequency axis on the graphic but I assume the left side of the screen is DC and the right side of the screen is half the sampling rate.

The sampling rate in the code was 4200 (I assume Hz) which would be way too low for audio and suggest the OP is seeing the aliasing of all higher frequencies above the Nyquist frequency of 2100 Hz. Since the audio system has a likely bandwidth of 15 KHz, any signals in multiples of 2100 Hz up through that frequency range would fold in and be a more obvious explanation of multiple frequencies due to aliasing.

I did change sampleRate to 44100 and it appeared (in my minimum ability to test) to behave more as expected.

Room echoes on their own should not be non-linear meaning they would not create new frequencies but only modify the phase and amplitude of the frequencies that already exist.

Comment: Sincere thanks. You are right on that left is DC and the very right is half the sampling rate. Each bar (frequency resolution) is 4 Hz (sampling frequency of ~4K and FFT size of ~1K). I made this more explicit in my code. I used sampling frequency of ~4K since I did not want to see notes above 2K Hz (attempting like of a LP filtering).

Comment: @MehmetDogan cool - I think it is interesting, email me boschen at loglin.com and I will help you get there. (and you can help me someday when/if I want to do more signal processing directly in javascript)

Comment: You are right that increasing the sampling frequency helps. I had tried that but seems I have failed to see it really making a difference. Thank you Dan!

Comment: Here I posted a higher sampling rate version: https://codepen.io/doganmeh/pen/RwadPeP. I also limited the visualization to 500 Hz max. Previously low frequency resolution was keeping us from seeing the duplicates, but they are still there.

Comment: @MehmetDogan Doesn't look right- and your sample rate is 65,536 but I really don't know how that affects the actual sampling rate at the microphone input (?). And strange how your results decay with time for a constant tone input. If I make the volume high we see lots of harmonics but may be due to expected results for saturation

Comment: I use this app https://apps.apple.com/us/app/erol-singers-studio/id502780186 (select Beginner 2, and hit play) to tune my voice to C3 (130 Hz).. that should be in the middle of the left half of the visualization given the range is now 500 Hz. I still see duplicates.

Comment: Yes I used the app. It seems to work as expected if I manually sweep the frequency, but statically the tone decays and goes away unless I turn it up loud in which case I see the duplicates at integer harmonics (which is expected for a saturated signal)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113398/discussion-between-dan-boschen-and-mehmet-dogan).

Comment: It usually respects the sampling rate. If it does not, the program does not work. You hit F12 (go to developer tools > console) and it tells you it has to be within a certain range.